# limitar el numero de respuestas introducidos por el usuario con prompt

Tags: javascript

Deseo que mi `prompt` **`se ejecute tres veces`** hasta que el usuario responda correctamente

```js
response = prompt("capital del italia");
        switch (response) { 
           case 'napoli':
                alert('falso') 
               break;
            case 'lombardia':
                alert('falso')
                break;
            case 'roma':
                 alert("correcto!")
                 break;
            case 'puglia': 
           alert('falso');  
          break;
            case 'sicilia': 
           alert('falso');  
          break;
         
       }
```

Comment: Hola steven, por favor, formula correctamente tu pregunta. Si lo que quieres es que alguien te resuelva tu ejercicio, tal vez estés en el lugar incorrecto. Si tienes algún problema con tu programa, especifica con precisión que problema es. El código que publiques debe corresponder __a lo que estás haciendo para resolver tu problema__.

Comment: ahora esta bien el titulo,?

Comment: Pues ya no importa, ya te hicieron la tarea =D. No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para que le den puntos de reputación a quien te contestó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución para mostrar el `Prompt` tres veces para dar la oportunidad de resolver la pregunta de forma correcta.

Otro detalle es que si no es igual a `'Roma'` , puede ir directamente a `default` del `Switch` , además de tener una variable `booleana` *(correcto)* que nos valide que la pregunta se respondió correctamente y un `entero` *(count)* para la cantidad de veces que se va mostrando el `prompt`.

```js
var count=1, correcto =false;
/* Si no se ah respondido
correctamente entra al while*/
while(!correcto){
 /* Si se agotaron las 3 oportunidades mostramos el mensaje
 y termine el Script*/
if(count>3) {
  alert('Se agotaron sus tres Oportunidades'); 
  break;
}
/* Caso Contrario mostramos el Prompt*/
else{
 response = prompt("Capital del italia");
 if(response=='roma'){
  correcto=true;
  alert('correcto');
 }
 else{
  count++;
  alert('incorrecto');
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: gracias tio me ahorraste dolores de cabeza, sin embargo creo que ya no hace falta usar el switch para hacer la evaluacion de dos opciones

Comment: @steven tienes mucha razón, bastaría con un `if else`